# Line spacing and font in table

Tags: tables, fonts, line-spacing

I am doing a document which needs double spacing and a font size of 12. I have the following lines of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

But I have noticed that the tables do not have double spacing or size 12, how can I solve it?

Comment: You probably need to repeat `\doublespacing` inside the `table` environment. Can you show a minimum working example that demonstrates the problem in question?

Comment: Your tables should use 12pt text as specified by the class option. What have you done to make them use another size? Provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.